# GNOME - How do you remove the power, sound, and internet panel indicator?

Tags: power-management, indicator, gnome-shell, applet

I am in the process of customizing my GNOME Desktop for a new Ubuntu derivative I am working on.

On the panel, there is a little indicator or applet, I don't know what it's called, but I need to remove it. Here's what I'd like to remove:

[image: Applet/Indicator Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Gnome Extension:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/351/icon-hider/

If you go into the settings for it you can disabling "aggregateMenu" will remove those three icons and in the next tab disabling "show extension's indicator" will remove the extension's own icon

Comment: This is the way. "aggregateMenu" would better be changed to the official name, i.e., "User Menu". That extension should indeed allow to remove it, provided it works on your version. Recent comments suggest it may have been broken by recent updates in Gnome Shell.